# ArcGIS for Desktop on Linux?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linux

Will ArcGIS 10 work properly on Linux using **[wine or crossweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeWeavers)**?

Comment: You may want to vote to bring [ArcGIS Desktop to Linux](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000boK7AAI)

Comment: You can try. Do you know how to install an application in wine? Just give it a go, it'll either work or not. Old applications generally do work, newer ones don't.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Answer was on James Fee's Blog from your question there.

*"For Linux: only ArcGIS Server, the ArcGIS Engine Runtime, and ArcReader, **but not** (likely ever) ArcGIS Desktop.
As for Desktop: why in the world would you even want to install that collection of buggy 32-bit COM objects on a nice, clean 64-bit Linux box 
If you want a Linux desktop with GIS, then the excellent GRASS/QGIS/PostGIS combo will do a lot more than 99% of most GIS users in the workforce will ever need, provided they are not all hung up on storing their spatial data in a proprietary format…"*

credit to GISpundit (and for the humour element)

http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/2010/03/10/so-there-will-be-an-esrimicrosoft-sig-at-the-devsummit/ comments

Comment: yup that was a response to a comment I made on that site. I only tried with 9.3 though

Comment: I know Mapperz never wrote the comment but I think avoiding anti (or pro) software rants should be avoided.

Comment: considering 64 bit applications are powerful (geo-processing would be 4xfaster) - yet ESRI ArcGIS platforms still remains a 32bit applications 10 years on.

Answer (score 14):

Not that I know of. It does however run just fine using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to emulate the OS itself, I've had no problems using ArcGIS in this configuration.

Comment: if you are running arcgis in a virtual box guest session, could you help me with this question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48957/13692

Answer (score 5):

Currently I am running ArcGIS10 in the last VirtalBox version (not the OSE version) under Ubuntu and it works very fine for the moment.