# Is ArcGIS available on Ubuntu?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, ubuntu, arcgis-platform

Is ESRI's ArcGIS platform of programs available on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)? I love open source and if I could I would love to try and migrate to this open source OS.

Comment: +1 may be useful http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/arcgis-10-on-linux

Comment: If you love open source forget the ESRI (ESRI term is not coming under open source) switch to QGIS +PostGIS .You will enjoy the open source : )

Comment: @Sunil I'd love to spend the time learning QGIS a little more. But presently ESRI's products are to ingrained in the industry that it's impossible to not use it for most projects.

Comment: that's true : )

Comment: I disagree, I took just a little time to use QGIS and now I use ESRI at all, it's worth you time and QGIS can do it all

Comment: Vote this up: [ArcGIS Idea for ESRI ArcGIS desktop for Ubuntu linux](https://c.na9.visual.force.com/apex/ideaView?id=08730000000boK7&mc=0) Although has ESRI ever actually put one of these ideas into motion?

Comment: QGIS 1.9 (alpha) has direct Oracle Spatial connection - making ESRI products redundant in our work.

Comment: ArcGIS - Only Redhat for Linux http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//01510000006s000000

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At present **ArcGIS Desktop is not supported on the Linux platform** but you can install Server platform software on Linux such as ArcGIS Server.

Updated :-

For more details please check [Similar question: ArcGIS for Desktop on Linux?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/arcgis-for-desktop-on-linux)

See also [Desktop GIS for Linux](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/desktop-gis-linux-introduction) (in Linux Journal)

Comment: I love that Linux Journal article. Good find!

Comment: Could you please update your post to address the dead link?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, only the backend software is available for Ubuntu (ArcServer, ArcSDK).  This is because many enterprise-level companies run Ubuntu, SUSE, or other Linux servers and Windows workstations.  However, ArcGIS is not the only fish in the sea.  Using free and open-source software, you can do almost everything that ArcGIS can, and a number of things that it can't.  If you already know how to use ArcMap, the learning curve going to QGIS or others is a lot less steep than you might expect.

I personally use an open source software stack on Ubuntu for a lot of my work.  Once I have time to learn the Python syntax for QGIS (PyQGIS), I may leave ArcMap behind.

Comment: I've used QGIS sporadically over the last year when ArcGIS fails me. I do enjoy it, but I'm in a very face paced job where quick turn-around's are everything. The time it would take me to do something in QGIS compared to ArcGIS isn't time I can afford. Either way, thanks for the answer, I may spend some free time learning QGIS better.

Comment: QGIS 1.9 (2.0) with direct editing with Oracle Spatial Connection is improving our workflow - now we do not need ESRI products.

Comment: @Mapperz  that's great : )

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go through the trouble you might be able to set up ArcGIS on a virtual machine running windows and run that through a Linux Platform.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Desktop is not currently available on Linux systems, but you can install ArcGIS Enterprise for Linux.
 : 
[the installation guide][1]http://enterprise.arcgis.com/fr/server/latest/install/linux/welcome-to-the-arcgis-for-server-install-guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

Server yes, Desktop No.  If you use cloud builder on AWS and choose the Linux install it will install on Ubuntu, using wine.  Strangely Ubuntu is not supported by esri on a standard install.  You can manually do the install on Ubuntu but you will have to work around some errors, it will work but you won't get support.  You other option is rhel which is supported up to v7.